# Permutation of a rank-$r$ matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, matrix-rank, block-matrices, permutation-matrices

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be a matrix of rank $r$. I believe that there always exist row and column permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that

$$P M Q = \left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  A
  \end{matrix}
  & B \\
\hline
  C &
  \begin{matrix}
  D
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}\right)$$

for an invertible $r \times r$ matrix  $A$. Is it correct? If it is, is it also possible to select the permutations in such a way that the maximal entry of the matrix is not in the block $D$?

Comment: Permutation matrices are orthogonal.  If you relax and consider general orthogonal matrices instead, then $P$ and $Q$ are the matrices of singular vectors.  Think of SVD

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first part of the quesion is "yes".Suppose the rank of $M$ is $r$ and $M$ has a non-singular sub-matrix in rows $a_1,...,a_r$ and columns $b_1,...,b_r$. Number the remaining rows and columns $a_{r+1},...,a_n$ and $b_{r+1},...b_m$ respectively.Let $P$ be the $n \times n$ matrix in which, for $1 \le i \le n$, the $i-$ th row has 1 in column $a_i$ and 0 elsewhere.Let $Q$ be the $m \times m$ matrix in which, for $1 \le j \le m$, the $j-$ th column has 1 in row $b_j$ and 0 elsewhere. Your second question is harder in the case that the maximum element of $M$ is not contained in any non-singular $r \times r$ sub-matrix of $M$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. For the second part, would you have an example of such a matrix with nonnegative entries ? When you say it's harder, do you mean that it can't be done in this case or simply that the existence of such a permutation is unclear ?